# PDFKit / PDFView Disable Interaction with Form Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, apple-pdfkit

For a `PDFDocument` that contains annotations with a `widgetFieldType` of `PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.text` and `PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button` is it possible to disable user interaction for those annotations (i.e. clicking on a checkbox does not cause it to toggle)?

Comment: can you share a sample pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (for first page):

```
        pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.annotations.filter {
            $0.widgetFieldType == PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button
            }.forEach {
                $0.shouldDisplay = false
            }
        }
```

Comment: does that hide the widget or disable user user interaction?

Comment: I tried it with a file with radio buttons and they were only disabled. Ymmv though depending on the file, that’s why I asked for a sample if you had one.

Comment: if annotation type is ".ink" then b setting "shouldDisplay = false" it hides it instead disabling user interaction.